# Expected time to reach the end of the line

Tags: probability, expectation, mathematical-modeling, negative-binomial, transition-matrix

Imagine we have six nodes, labeled 0 through 5. One can transition from node $i$ to $i+1$ with probability $p$ or can remain at node $i$ with probability $1-p$. Note that once one transitions to a node, it cannot backtrack. See the following figure for an illustration.

[image]

I want to know the expected time it takes to reach node 5 assuming you start at node 0. I started to write down the following outcomes below:

- 5 transitions, 0 stops (5 time-steps)
- 5 transitions, 1 stop (6 time-steps)
- 5 transitions, 2 stops (7 time-steps)
- and so on...

where "stop" means no transition was made. Once we list all of the cases then it's just a matter of computing the probabilities. Problem is, I don't know how to write out all of the cases (infinitely many?). Is this the right way of thinking about it?

Comment: The expected number of moves to go to the next state is $1/p$. So you need on average $5/p$ moves to go from 0 to 5.

Comment: Thank you. If we write out the cases, does the following hold: $5p^5+6p^5(1-p)+7p^5(1-p)^2 + 8p^5(1-p)^3+\cdots = 5/p$?

Comment: I am not sure if that series is right ( shouldn't $5p^5$ be $p^5$?), but yes. You can write it as a powered series representing all possible cases.

Comment: If you want more details, let $E$ be the expected time for transition from a state to a higher state.
Since with probability $1-p$ we need one more move
$$E=p+(1-p)(E+1)\implies pE=1\implies E=\frac{1}{p}$$

Comment: Related? [Random walk on a cube](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454444/random-walk-on-a-cube)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way to approach this problem is to take advantage of linearity of expectation by expressing the transit time as a sum of i.i.d. geometrically-distributed random variables, as in [Daniel Xiang’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2094260/265466), but it can certainly be attacked the way you propose: by computing the probability that it takes a given number of time steps to reach the end and then finding the sum of the infinite series that directly results from the definition of expectation.

Let $Y$ count the number of time steps to transit the chain. Since every transit takes at least five steps, we’ll focus on the probabilities of extra time being taken—of there being $k$ stops during the transit. Let the random variable $X=Y-5$ count these extra steps. As you’ve already determined, $\Pr(X=k)$ is equal to $p^5(1-p)^k$ times a coefficient that counts the number of ways that the stops can be distributed throughout the transit. This is a typical [stars-and-bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), from which we can easily work out this coefficient: $$\Pr(X=k)=\binom{4+k}4p^5(1-p)^k$$ so $$E[X]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\Pr(X=k)=p^5\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\binom{4+k}4(1-p)^k=p^5{5-5p\over p^6}=5{1-p\over p}$$ and $$E[Y]=5+E[X]=\frac5p.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $T_i$ be the time it takes to reach node $i$ for $i = 1, ..., 5$.

Then the total time $T$ it takes for one to reach node 6 from node 0 can be written as a sum
\begin{align*}
T = T_1 + \dots + T_5
\end{align*}
So the expected value of $T$ is
\begin{align*}
ET = \sum_1^5 ET_i \stackrel{(*)}{=} \sum_1^5 \frac{1}{p} = \frac{5}{p}
\end{align*}

$(*)$ Since each $T_i$ is distributed $\sim$ Geom($p$)

Answer (score 0):

You can model the number of steps to reach the destination as a [Negative Binomial](https://books.google.com/books?id=s-d6DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA255&lpg=PA255&dq=negative+binomial+random+variable+%22r+successes%22&source=bl&ots=A9PIuLGyc-&sig=LcXJSdtckjmxIOPeZm5jU23UZZg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbq9Dj1LvRAhUhDcAKHVo-Bdo4ChDoAQg3MAY#v=onepage&q=negative%20binomial%20random%20variable%20%22r%20successes%22&f=false) random variable $X$ with parameters $r=5$ (number of successes) and $p$. The success is moving to the right (with probability $p$ and the failure is staying in the same position.

The expectation of a Negative Binomial random variable is:

$$E[X]=\frac{r}{p}=\frac{5}{p}$$