# Markov chain on an $n$-dimensional hypercube?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, expected-value

I am looking at the following Cambridge Tripos question, which has left me rather stumped for quite a while.

> A particle moves on the $2^n$ vertices of the hypercube $\{0,1\}^n$. At each step the particle is equally likely to move to each of the $n$ adjacent vertices, independently of its past motion. The initial vertex occupied by the particle is $(0,0,...,0)$. Calculate the expected number of steps until the particle
>
> i) first returns to $0,0,...,0)$;
>
> ii) first visits $(0,0,...,1)$;
>
> iii) first visits $(0,0,...,1,1)$.

I have seen multiple answers on here regarding the 3D case, as well as a general $D$-dimensional case presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28179/logic-question-ant-walking-a-cube), but I am quite stuck on generalising to other vertices, including the three presented here. Would be lovely to see some guidance here, thanks!

Comment: I'd probably try to do it numerically for a few cases and try to see a pattern.

Comment: Does this answer your question? (Further generalisation also included) [Expected hitting times for simple random walk on a hypercube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704167/expected-hitting-times-for-simple-random-walk-on-a-hypercube)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2018 Part IB Paper 2 Q20H if anybody is looking.  Also asked in 1991.  The introductory part to the question was

> For a finite irreducible Markov chain, what is the relationship
> between the invariant probability distribution and the mean recurrence
> times of states?

which can be applied here to give the answer for (i) of $2^n$ given the symmetry of the hypercube

If we call the expectation when starting zero steps away from the end point $E_0=2^n$, when starting one step away $E_1$, and starting two steps away $E_2$ then:

- for (ii) we can say $E_0=1+\frac{n}{n}E_1$ as you start by stepping one step from the start, making $E_1 = 2^{n}-1$
- similarly for (iii) we can say $E_1=1+\frac1n0 +\frac{n-1}{n}E_2$ as you start by stepping one step either to the end point or (more likely) to somewhere two steps away  $E_2=\frac{n}{n-1}(2^n-2)$

The pattern continues: in general for $1 \lt k \lt n$ you have $E_k=1+\frac kn E_{k-1} +\frac{n-1}{n} E_{k+1}$ so can find $E_{k+1}$ from $E_{k}$ and $E_{k-1}$.  And finally for the diametrically opposite corner you will have $E_n=1+E_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

For (i), note that the Markov chain $(X_n)$ is clearly irreducible, so since the state space is finite, it is positive recurrent. So there is a stationary distribution, which by symmetry is just $\pi(v)=1/2^n$ for all vertices $v$. So the expected first return time is the inverse of this, i.e. $2^n$.

Now let $T_k$ be the mean time to hit the origin from a vertex of distance $k$ away, with $T_0=2^n$ as above.

For (ii), we want $T_1$. But clearly $T_0=1+T_1\implies T_1=2^n-1$.

For (iii), we want to find $T_2$. Just note that after two steps, either we are back at the origin (with probability $1/n$) , or we end up a distance $2$ away. So
$$T_0=2+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot T_2\implies T_2=\frac{n\left(2^n-2\right)}{n-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought:

Let $w(x)$ denote the weight of $x\in\{0,1\}^n$, i.e., $w(x)=\sum x_j$. There is no one-step path between two $x$'s with the same weight; taking each step, the weight changes by $+1$ or $-1$. Take the weight as the state, so, there exist $n+1$ states associated with the weights. Let $p_{i}^+$ denote the probability of transition from state $i$ to state $i+1$, and $p_i^-$ denote the transition from state $i$ to $i-1$, then $p_i^-=\frac{i}{n}$, and $p_{i}^+=1-\frac{i}{n}$.

At each state, due to the symmetry of hyper-cube, members are equiprobable, i.e., the probability of visiting a specific member of $i^{th}$ state, given you are at the $i^{th}$ state, is$\dfrac{1}{{n\choose i}}$.

I suspect that it builds a simple Markov model to answer the question.

Comment: This seems like a "long term" view, which doesn't totally work if you have an initial distribution other than the invariant one. Except for the recurrence time question.

Comment: True. However, I think under the described scenario, the MC is in stationary state from the get go. Please feel free to edit my answer. It is basically just a hunch, not a complete answer.

Comment: And I think you are right. It only works (if it works) if you are interested in the recurrence time.

Comment: It's definitely not initially stationary, it's initially at a particular vertex almost surely. This doesn't impede the matter of finding the expected return time, but it does impede the matter of finding the expected time to reach a particular other state.

Comment: Hmm... You certainly have a point. But let's look at it this way: the particle has been moving around forever, now we look at it and observe that it is in a particular state, and we are interested in the expected number of steps for the particle to reach another state. I think such a system is stationary, and I cannot picture how it is different from the problem in hand. Maybe I am missing something. I too feel that my approach is too simple to be true! I too am looking for the flaw in it.

Comment: No, once you know it's in a particular state, you've changed the distribution of where it is.